# Can we quantize Maxwell-Chern-Simon Theory through Gupta-Bleuler approach?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, chern-simons-theory

In 3+1 QED we covariant quantize the Maxwell theory through Gupta-Bleuler method. But I have seen that MCS theory is explicitly covariant quantized using Nakanishi auxiliary field. Why cannot we take the following form and covariant quantize the theory.

$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+ \frac{\mu}{4} \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha} F_{\mu\nu}A_{\alpha}   -\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu})^2$

I hope there will be some issue with constraints in both cases but I could not get the point. Kindly some one guide me.

Comment: Of course constrained canonical quantization a la Gupta-Bleuler is in principle *possible* for every constrained theory. It may just be too computationally involved (e.g involve differential equations that are impossible to analytically solve) to be actually *feasible* (just like reduced phase space quantization is also in principle possible, but no one ever does that), so I am not quite sure what your question is

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Consider adding references (of what you already are reading) to make the question more accessible to the reader and focus the answers.

Comment: could you plz give me some refrnces to stdy explicitly solved examples?